# Clearing a radio list with a function - ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an ionic app. On one of the pages I have a radio list. Now the problem is, when I go to the next screen and then pop back, the radio list is not cleared, which is bad UX. I see two possible ways:

- either a function that will uncheck my list (which I could then throw into ionViewWillEnter) - which would be best. I played with the [checked], but does not seem to be much help.
- or a way to not cache this particular page

I have searched quite a lot how to do either and haven't found much. Any ideas?

The code for my list is:

```
        <ion-list radio-group class="size-list">
            <ion-list-header class="size-list-header" text-center>
                {{"Size and prices" | translate}}
            </ion-list-header>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of menuItems.price; let i= index" class="size-list-item">
                <ion-label *ngIf="item.specialPrice"> {{item.pname}}
                    <span class="cut">
                        ${{item.value}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="offer-p">
                        ${{item.specialPrice |number:0}}
                    </span>
                </ion-label>
                <ion-label *ngIf="!item.specialPrice">
                    {{item.pname}} ${{item.value}}
                </ion-label>
                <ion-radio class="checked" [checked]="isChecked==true" (ionSelect)="sizeOptions(item)"></ion-radio>   
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: The `ionViewWillEnter` makes sense, why didn't it work?

Comment: Good question. I try to use the [checked] attribute, but it only seems to work one way. Meaning: if I have a TS button that sets 

this.isChecked = false;

then nothing happens after that button is clicked. But if that button has:

this.isChecked = true;

then it 'works' i.e. all the radio options are selected, which is exactly the opposite of what I need

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you use `FormGroup` and `FormControl` to be able to access your `ion-radio` and initialize it to `false` in your constructor.
I can further elaborate it for you if you like

Answer (score 0):

thanks to dou2abou's help I figured it out.

In this case: 
1. wrap your list in an angular form.
2. use the reset() form control.

so in my .ts i now have:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'


export class ProductDetailsPage {
  options;
  optionsForm;
}

  constructor() {
    this.optionsForm = new FormGroup({
      "options": new FormControl()});
    }

  resetList() {
    this.optionsForm.controls.options.reset()
  }
}
```

and in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="optionsForm">
    <ion-list radio-group class="size-list" formControlName="options">
    </ion-list>
</form>
```